# Generating DateTimeOffsets for a 'local' time range

Tags: c#, timezone, datetimeoffset

I'm unsure how best to approach a date/time problem in C#. I have a dataset which lists the working hours for a set of people. Basically, 'person X works 09:00 to 17:30, Monday-Friday'. Basically two `TimeSpan`-s, which are assumed to be local times for any given date. From this, I need to be able to create two `DateTimeOffset`-s for any day of the year for a given locale.

For example, if I wanted to generate the UK-based `DateTimeOffset` for the following dates, I'd get the following results:

```
2015-01-01: From 2015-01-01T09:00:00+00:00, to 2015-01-01T17:30:00+00:00
2015-07-01: From 2015-01-07T09:00:00+01:00, to 2015-01-07T17:30:00+01:00
```

Obviously the difference is just the timezone - the first is GMT, the second is BST. A working day isn't normally affected by time zone changes. This is dependent on the date given.

I need to be able to do this for any specified country / region, including those whose timezones change (as demoed above).

If it matters, this will be .NET on Windows.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use the `GetUtcOffset` method on the `TimeZoneInfo` class, then use it in the `DateTimeOffset` constructor.  Alternatively, look in to [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).

Comment: Sounds like it'll do the trick. I'll have a look into using Nodatime too, thanks.